# NotificationObject update all properties on reference re-assignment

Tags: wpf, binding

When your view entity derives from NotificationObject and each property calls the "RaiseProperty" change in its setter, will all properties call "RaiseProperty" on object reassignment. Or do you have set each property manually when you want to notify WPF controls of property changes.

Ex.

1. Item/entity arrives from WCF.
2. Item that is already in an observable collection detects that the arrived item is already contained in the collection and should check for any properties that are different between item already in collection and item that arrived from WCF.

Can I do this?

EntityInCollection = EntityFromWCF and have each property raise its event? Or do I have to do this:

EntityInCollection.Property1 = EntityFromWCF.Property1... etc. for each property.

I have a gridview diplaying object and would like to animate the cells that get updated but I'm thinking that reassigning the reference will raise all events and not simply the ones that have changed/are different between the two objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're replacing the entire object, the ObservableCollection will raise an event to notify of this change. UI components will (or should - I can't vouch for all controls, especially 3rd party ones) respond and refresh automatically.